# How do I select the next "select" (dropdown) in this HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My html is:

```
    <tr>
        <td><select id = "delAppSelectApp" name="delAppSelectApp"><option value="--Select--"> --Select--</option></select></td>
        <td><select id = "delAppSelectAppVers" name="delAppSelectAppVers"><option value="--Select--">--Select--</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submitDelAppVers" id="submitDelAppVers" value="Delete Application Version" /></td>
    </tr>
```

My script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delAppSelectApp").change(function(){
        alert( $(this).nextAll("select").attr("id") );
    });
});
```

I want the window to alert "delAppSelectAppVers", which is not happening. What am I doing wrong ? I've even tried the "siblings" function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delAppSelectApp").change(function() {
        alert( $(this).closest("td").next().find('select').attr("id") );
    });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7twmJ/

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the there is no "next" element (sibling) at the same level within the node xpath/axis. Try this:

```
$(this).parent.next().children("select:first").attr("id")
```